# css3 3d transform, div become not available

Tags: html, css

I have a cube with two sides (front-side, right-side), when I rotate the сube on `-90deg`, right-side becomes not available (can't select text, can't click buttons), but if I rotate on `-90.1deg` right-side becomes available. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```css
body{perspective-origin:600px;}
    
.cube{
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform:rotateY(-90deg); /*not work*/
}

.side{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px
}

.front-side{transform:translateZ(100px);}
.right-side{transform:translateX(100px) rotateY(90deg);}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side front-side">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, deleniti.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nam magni earum quas consectetur, rerum in aliquam illo perferendis sapiente!</div>
    <div class="side right-side">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore dolor eius corrupti!   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias saepe, doloribus porro nam distinctio culpa accusamus delectus harum nostrum provident.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cube` class has collapsed that's why the child element not accessible. make the `cube` content with width/height dimention and relative position.

Please have a look at the snippet.

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
var degree = document.getElementById('degree');
document.getElementById('rotate').addEventListener('input', function() {
  cube.style.transform = 'rotateY(' + this.value + 'deg)';
  degree.innerHTML = this.value + ' deg';
});
```

```css
body {
  perspective-origin: 600px;
}

.cube {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /*not work*/
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.front-side {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.right-side {
  transform: translateX(100px) rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side front-side">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, deleniti.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nam magni earum quas consectetur, rerum in aliquam illo perferendis sapiente!</div>
    <div class="side right-side">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore dolor eius corrupti! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias saepe, doloribus porro nam distinctio culpa accusamus delectus harum nostrum provident.</div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="any" id="rotate" /> <span id="degree">0 deg</span>
</body>
```